# SoX vs. FFmpeg - FLAC conversion file size

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, sox

Usually I'm using SoX to convert audio files to FLAC, but I would like to remove it and have one less requirement needed.

However, with technically identical settings, the files that I'm converting are still larger than the ones converted with SoX. How can I change this?

```shell
sox \
    File.wav \
    -b 16 -D \
    -C 8 \
    --comment "" \
    File_SoX.flac

ffmpeg -y -loglevel -8 \
    -i File.wav -af \
    aresample=osf=s16:dither_method=none \
    -compression_level 12 \
    -fflags +bitexact -flags:v +bitexact -flags:a +bitexact -map 0 -map_metadata 0:s:0  \
    File_FFmpeg.flac
```

---

- `wc -c File_SoX.flac`

  - `16835` bytes
- `wc -c File_FFmpeg.flac`

  - `24644` bytes

Comment: It is just a property of the different encoders that they use. you cannot change that without getting them to use the same encoders and it might also due to the metadata that ffmpeg adds to the outputs